# Find the median of a group of data and apply to members of that group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How do you get the median of a group and and then apply that to all member that belong to the group?

I have a large dataframe that individuals in column 1, the group that they belong to in column 2, and their scores in column 3.

I would like to get the median of the group and then assign that in column 4 to members of that group. Different median for every group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert strings representation of numeric and also convert non numeric to `NaN`s, then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `median` for new column in original data filled aggregate values:

```
df['score'] = pd.to_numeric(df['score'], errors='coerce')
df['median'] = df.groupby('col2')['score'].transform('median')
```

Comment: i get ```DataError: No numeric types to aggregate```

Comment: @hkml - Can you test now?